# How to use redux-promise-middleware with react-scripts v3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-promise-middleware

I recently updated my `react-scripts` to version `3.0.0` in my React application and all of my actions stopped working.

I am using `redux-promise-middleware` so I have always this pattern when fetching data:

```
export const FIRST_ACTION = 'FIRST_ACTION';
export const FIRST_ACTION_PENDING = 'FIRST_ACTION_PENDING';
export const FIRST_ACTION_REJECTED = 'FIRST_ACTION_REJECTED';
export const FIRST_ACTION_FULFILLED = 'FIRST_ACTION_FULFILLED';
```

**store.js**:

```
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, promiseMiddleware(), logger)
    );
}
```

I am usually performing several requests in a chain in my actions like this:

```
import { 
    firstAction,
    secondAction
} from '../service';

const chainedAction = (...) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch({
            type: FIRST_ACTION,
            payload: firstAction(...)
        }).then(() => dispatch({
            type: SECOND_ACTION,
            payload: secondAction(...)
        }));
    };
};
```

After the update, I am getting the following errors:

```
React Hook "firstAction" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Does anybody know how to migrate my actions so they will be compliant with the latest dependencies?

EDIT: I am importing this action in my react component and calling it from there:

```
import { 
    chainedAction
} from '../actions';
...
<Button onClick={(...) => chainedAction(...)}
...
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators({ 
        chainedAction
    }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyPage);
```

**firstAction** (second action is similar):

```
export const firstAction = (...) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(API_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: ...
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                resolve(response.text());
            }

            reject('...');
        }).catch(error => {
            return reject(error.message);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: It seems that react and redux were updated that caused problems I guess

Comment: It's right there in the error. You're trying to use a react hook outside of a react component.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with "two actions in a row" and everything to do with violating [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions). Assuming we're in the context of a component, make your calls to the hooks prior to `chainedAction`, store them in local variables and use the locals in then callbacks.

Comment: Mate, this has nothing to do with redux. This is React complaining that you're using a hook `useState`, `useReducers`, `useMemo`, etc. outside of a React component. The only way to fix this is to move the logic inside a react component OR only use the external hook inside the component.

Comment: How does firstAction look like?

Comment: There seems to be no use of hook anywhere in your code.Could you provide a reproducible demo on codesandbox ?

Comment: I am not using any hooks as far as I know. That's why I am so confused. It seems that `react-sripts` v3 introduced some breaking changes and I will probably have to stick with the older version.

Comment: uploaded push the project in the in githup or repl maybe i help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the error. One of my function was called `useCOnsumable`. Because of the `use` prefix, React thought that it is a hook and complained. It had nothing to do with `redux-promise-middleware`.

Once I renamed the invalid function, the migration was pretty painless.